# how to order by data descending with findAll query using grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

Here is my code:

```
Notification.all.findAll{it.actionTeamBy != null && it.user.id == params?.getLong('user_id') && it.status == true}
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for standard [Iterable sorting](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort()) that is done after the `findAll` call.

```
assert [3,4,2,7,4].sort() == [2, 3, 4, 4, 7]
```

So that would translate into something like this

```
Notification.all.findAll {
    it.actionTeamBy != null && it.status == true &&
            it.user.id == params?.getLong('user_id')
}.sort { a, b ->
    // implement sorting mechanism here
    // b.id <=> a.id // could work for you
}
```